# Clicking on the play button should fade orange background into another color

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions

This is what I have, I’m confused on how that would be set up.

What I want to occur is, after the button is clicked, I would want the orange to change to another color. Fade to another color.

`.slide` would need to be used for the animation to occur.

Similar to how `.slide` is used here:

```
.curtain1.slide .video-one {
  transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 1px));
}
```

How would I do this in the code? https://jsfiddle.net/yo9amjub/

```
  function openCurtain(curtain) {
    curtain.classList.add("slide");
  }

.video-one {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 8s ease-in 0s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  background: orange;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: fadeInImage 2s ease-in 2s forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes fadeInImage {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the goal is to make the orange box fade into another color while moving up at the same time, add this to the css code:

```
.video-one::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 5s ease-in 2s;
  background-color: pink;
}

.curtain1.slide .video-one::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

To change which color for the orange box to fade into, edit `background-color: pink;` and change `pink` to a desired color.

To change the timing of the color fade, edit `transition: opacity 5s ease-in 2s;` first value `5s` sets the duration for the secondary color to emerge, second value `2s` sets the delay before the color fade starts.

The idea is to create a pseudo-element at the same position and on top of the orange box. This has the secondary color as background but is initially hidden with 0 opacity. When the orange box slides, turn it to full opacity with a transition to achieve the color-fade effect.